# Is it possible to unlock a PDF created by ColdFusion?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am pretty sure I know the answer is no, but wanted to confirm with others.

Can you take a PDF document created by ColdFusion 8 via the following tag and remove the password protection so that changes can be made to the PDF, especially being able to add additional pages?

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" overwrite="true" encryption="128-bit" permissions="AllowPrinting" unit="in" margintop=".9" marginbottom=".5" marginright=".5" marginleft=".5">
```

As you can see no password is provided, this no password exists to pass into any method that would unlock the file.

Comment: This is similar to your question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47560/what-are-the-vulnerabilities-of-using-a-256-bit-encrypted-pdf-file-over-email

Comment: It is just a hunch, but what happens when you open the document in Acrobat, change the security setting and do not enter a password? It is possible that the encryption has been made, but no password has been set.

Comment: That's not my question.

Comment: If I try to change to no security, and leave the password blank, I get "You do not have permission to change security settings."

Comment: As far as I remember, ColdFusion uses an ancient version of iText. If you encrypt a PDF without a user password, a random owner password is generated. You can use iText to remove that random password as described in my answer to the question [How to read PDFs created with an unknown random owner password?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-read-pdfs-created-unknown-random-owner-password)

Comment: [see here](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2009/01/23/How-to-remove-a-password-from-a-PDF-using-ColdFusion/)